# How can I route to index.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I need route to `index.html.erb`? How can I do it? I tried `root "index.html.erb#index"` in `routes.rb`.

Comment: Advice 1: "I" is always capital case on English. Advice 2: Give more details: a) what exactly you did, b) what you wanted c) what happened. We aren't telepaths, but we would be happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in rails we set routes for our controller's method not for our
view file. Get method of controller redirect to view the page itself.

Write below code in your `routes.rb`:

```
get 'index', to: 'controller_name#index'
```

You can replace `get 'index'` with any name like `get 'users'`.

You can refer [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/routing.html) for more reference.